# How to upload multiple pdf file to Magento Manufacturer

Tags: php, magento

I would like to upload multiple pdf with manufacturer how can I do this in magento? I am able to upload logo of manufacturer with [plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manufacturer-brand-logo.html), but I can't add multiple pdf files with manufacture. Can someone guide me with code or plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have customize this plugin as I need

I have add this code in plugin form.php file

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read'); 
            $select = $connection->select()
                ->from('manufacturer_pdf', array('*')) // select * from tablename or use array('id','title') selected values
                ->where('menufecturer_name=?',Mage::registry('manufacturer_data')->getData('menufecturer_name'))               // where id =1
                ->group('pdfname');               // group by title

            $_SESSION['adminmanufacuterquery']=$rowsArray = $connection->fetchAll($select); // return all rows
            $rowArray =$connection->fetchRow($select);   //return row
            $i=1;
            foreach($rowsArray as $key=>$pdf){              
                $_SESSION['admindbmanufacuter']="yes";
                $name=$pdf['pdfname'];

                $fieldset->addField('pdfnameload'.$key, 'hidden', array(                       
                        'required'  => false,
                        'name'      => 'hidden',                        
                        'after_element_html' => '<span id="pdfrow'.$key.'" class="hint"><a href="'.Mage::getBaseUrl('media')."Manufacturer/".$name.'">'.$name.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><input type="hidden" name="oldpdf'.$key.'" value="'.$pdf['manufacturer_id'].'" /></span><span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test('.$key.');">Delete</span></span>'
                    ));
                    $_SESSION['mycustomefield']=$i;$i++;
            }
```

for save in database

```
if(isset($_FILES['pdfname']['name']) && $_FILES['pdfname']['name'] != '') {                 
                        foreach($_FILES['pdfname']['name'] as $key=>$pdf){                          
                            if(isset($pdf) && $pdf != '') {
                                $pdfname=explode(".", $pdf); 
                                if($pdfname[1]=='pdf'){ 
                                    $connectionWrite = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                                    $pdf= str_replace(" ","_",$pdf);
                                    $newdata['pdfname']= time().'_'.$pdf;
                                    $newdata['menufecturer_name']=$data['menufecturer_name'];                       
                                    $connectionWrite->insert('manufacturer_pdf', $newdata);


                                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ."Manufacturer".DS; 
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdfname']['tmp_name'][$key],$path.$newdata['pdfname']);

                                    $connectionWrite->commit();
                                }else{
                                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("Upload PDF Files Only");
                                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                                    return;
                                }   
                            }
                        }   
                    }
```